# Congruence equation problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem statement

Find a number $n$ such that $n$ is the product of two different primes and such that the congruence equation $X^2+1=0 \text{(mod n)}$ has exactly four different solutions modulo $n$. Calculate the solutions for the found value.

My attempt at a solution

I really don't get how to solve this problem. All I could think of is that if $n=ab$ with $a \neq b$ and $a,b$ primes, then $X^2+1=0 \text{(mod a)}$ and $X^2+1=0 \text{(mod b)}$. This hasn't help me since now I have two equations instead of one to solve.

I would appreciate if someone could suggest me one way to solve the problem

Comment: have you already tried some primes $a$ and $b$ and found the $x$ for which $x^2+1\equiv 0\mod ab$?

Comment: Now I'll try it combining $a,b \in \{2,3,5,7\}$, I thought that the exercise could be solved using some theorem or property instead of just plugging values and see if it works. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Even if it is possible, it is always a good idea to get to know how the number of solutions depends on $a$ and $b$. Probably, you want to find two solutions for $x^2+1\equiv 0\mod a$ and also two solutions for the second equation. Then you can use the Chinese remainder theorem to find four solutions $\mod ab$.

Comment: Hint: The congruence has $2$ solutions for the primes $5,13,17,29,37,\dots$.

Comment: I'll use that hint. By the way, did you realize about this plugging these numbers and checking if it worked?

Comment: Well a solution to $X^{2} + 1 = 0 \text{(mod p)}$ with p prime exists if and only if p is 2 or of the form $4k + 1$...hope that it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you take primes $p$ and $q$ for which $-1$ is a square ($p,q=1(mod 4)$), then the Chinese remainder theorem will give you 4 solutions $(mod pq)$. To be more precise, if $a^2=-1(mod p)$ and $b^2=-1(mod q)$, then you can consider the four systems $x=a(mod p),x=b(mod q)$; $x=-a(mod p),x=b(mod q)$; $x=a(mod p),x=-b(mod q)$; $x=-a(mod p),x=-b(mod q)$ and apply the Chinese remainder theorem to each of them. If $m$ is a solution of one of the systems, then $m^2=-1(mod p)$ and $m^2=-1(mod q)$, so $m^2=-1(mod pq)$.